# Converting .py to .exe : Cant understand code

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

```
> from distutils.core import setup 
  import py2exe 
  setup (windows =['keylogger.pyw'],
>        options = { 'py2exe' : {'packages':['Tkinter']}})
```

I'm tryna make a keylogger that works without prompting cmd. This code converts the keylogger.py to keylogger.exe 
I read the documentations, but I can't seem to put them all together.
Could someone patch it up for me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make an exe; just rename the file with a .pyw extension to bypass the command prompt window. Your installer should have associated that with C:\Windows\pyw.exe; if not you may need to make that association.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all your imports, and add `bundle` key:

```
setup(
    windows=[{"script":"keylogger.pyw"}],
    options = {"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1, "compressed": True, "includes":["Tkinter"]}},
    zipfile=None)
```